# Filter criteria with contextual Filter not working for content type node date

Tags: views

I need SEO friendly URL such as www.example.com/gallery/photos/2015

I need to filter the results using year with a Select year drop down.

What I have done for filtering:

1. I have set the Filter criteria to 'content: Post date' and exposed filter (year). So the filter drop down is displayed.
2. After this I wrote jquery to go to url www.example.com/gallery/photos/[year] , when a particular [year] is selected.
3. And added a contextual filter with 'content: Post date' for this to work.

OUTCOME:
'No results behaviour' is displayed when there is no result, but nothing is displayed when there is result.

**Question**:
**Why does the page do not print any results for any year when there is content for that year?
eg: www.example.com/gallery/photos/2015**

Also my friend suggested to use Filter harmonizer module , but its option is not displayed for node date content. Not sure whats happening. Please give your valued answers.

This is view export code:

```
 $view = new view();
$view->name = 'image_galleries';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->human_name = 'Image Galleries';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'some';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '5';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['default_row_class'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['row_class_special'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
$handler->display->display_options['row_options']['default_field_elements'] = FALSE;
/* No results behavior: Global: Text area */
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['id'] = 'area';
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['field'] = 'area';
/* Field: Content: Nid */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['id'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['field'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Gallery Images */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_images']['id'] = 'field_gallery_images';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_images']['table'] = 'field_data_field_gallery_images';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_images']['field'] = 'field_gallery_images';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_images']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_images']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_images']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_images']['settings'] = array(
  'link' => 0,
);
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_images']['delta_offset'] = '0';
/* Field: Content: Gallery Thumbnail */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_thumbnail']['id'] = 'field_gallery_thumbnail';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_thumbnail']['table'] = 'field_data_field_gallery_thumbnail';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_thumbnail']['field'] = 'field_gallery_thumbnail';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_thumbnail']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_thumbnail']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_thumbnail']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_thumbnail']['click_sort_column'] = 'fid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_thumbnail']['settings'] = array(
  'image_style' => '',
  'image_link' => '',
);
/* Field: Content: Image Gallery Subtitle */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image_gallery_subtitle']['id'] = 'field_image_gallery_subtitle';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image_gallery_subtitle']['table'] = 'field_data_field_image_gallery_subtitle';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image_gallery_subtitle']['field'] = 'field_image_gallery_subtitle';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image_gallery_subtitle']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image_gallery_subtitle']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image_gallery_subtitle']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Image Gallery Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image_gallery_title']['id'] = 'field_image_gallery_title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image_gallery_title']['table'] = 'field_data_field_image_gallery_title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image_gallery_title']['field'] = 'field_image_gallery_title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image_gallery_title']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image_gallery_title']['alter']['alter_text'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image_gallery_title']['alter']['text'] = '<div id="[field_image_gallery_title]" class="album">
    <div class="slide-header slide-title">
        <h1>[field_image_gallery_title]</h1>
        <h2>[field_image_gallery_subtitle]</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-slider multimedia-slider">
        <div class="slide">
            <img class="img-responsive" data-lazy="gallery image goes here">
            <div class="slide-caption">
                Gallery Image Caption <span class="photo-credit">Gallery Image Photo 
                Credits</span> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image_gallery_title']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image_gallery_title']['element_wrapper_type'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image_gallery_title']['element_default_classes'] = FALSE;
/* Sort criterion: Content: Image Gallery Order (field_image_gallery_order) */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['field_image_gallery_order_value']['id'] = 'field_image_gallery_order_value';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['field_image_gallery_order_value']['table'] = 'field_data_field_image_gallery_order';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['field_image_gallery_order_value']['field'] = 'field_image_gallery_order_value';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['field_image_gallery_order_value']['order'] = 'DESC';
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = array(
  'image_gallery' => 'image_gallery',
);
/* Filter criterion: Date: Date (node) */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['id'] = 'date_filter';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['field'] = 'date_filter';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['exposed'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['expose']['operator_id'] = 'date_filter_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['expose']['label'] = 'Select Year';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['expose']['operator'] = 'date_filter_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['expose']['identifier'] = 'date_filter';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['expose']['remember_roles'] = array(
  2 => '2',
  1 => 0,
  11 => 0,
);
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['granularity'] = 'year';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['date_fields'] = array(
  'node.created' => 'node.created',
);

/* Display: Image Gallery Block Featured */
$handler = $view->new_display('block', 'Image Gallery Block Featured', 'block');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['pager'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'some';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['offset'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['fields'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Nid */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['id'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['field'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Gallery Images */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_images']['id'] = 'field_gallery_images';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_images']['table'] = 'field_data_field_gallery_images';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_images']['field'] = 'field_gallery_images';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_images']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_images']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_images']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_images']['settings'] = array(
  'link' => 0,
);
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_images']['delta_offset'] = '0';
/* Field: Content: Gallery Thumbnail */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_thumbnail']['id'] = 'field_gallery_thumbnail';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_thumbnail']['table'] = 'field_data_field_gallery_thumbnail';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_thumbnail']['field'] = 'field_gallery_thumbnail';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_thumbnail']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_thumbnail']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_thumbnail']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_thumbnail']['click_sort_column'] = 'fid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_thumbnail']['type'] = 'image_url';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_thumbnail']['settings'] = array(
  'url_type' => '1',
  'image_style' => '',
  'image_link' => '',
);
/* Field: Content: Image Gallery Subtitle */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image_gallery_subtitle']['id'] = 'field_image_gallery_subtitle';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image_gallery_subtitle']['table'] = 'field_data_field_image_gallery_subtitle';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image_gallery_subtitle']['field'] = 'field_image_gallery_subtitle';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image_gallery_subtitle']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image_gallery_subtitle']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image_gallery_subtitle']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Image Gallery Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image_gallery_title']['id'] = 'field_image_gallery_title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image_gallery_title']['table'] = 'field_data_field_image_gallery_title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image_gallery_title']['field'] = 'field_image_gallery_title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image_gallery_title']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image_gallery_title']['alter']['alter_text'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image_gallery_title']['alter']['text'] = '          <h1>Photos</h1>
        <section  id="block-block-2" class="gallery-featured-area">
          <div class="slide-header slide-title">
            <span class="pointer">&raquo;</span> [field_image_gallery_title]
          </div>
          <a href="#!album=[nid]" id="gallery-featured" data-gallery="[nid]">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="[field_gallery_thumbnail]">
              <div class="slide-caption"><strong><span class="pointer">&raquo;</span></strong> [field_image_gallery_subtitle]</div>
          </a>
        </section>

        <div class="overlay"></div>';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image_gallery_title']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image_gallery_title']['element_wrapper_type'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image_gallery_title']['element_default_classes'] = FALSE;

/* Display: Gallery Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Gallery Page', 'page_1');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['title'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Photos';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['css_class'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['css_class'] = 'photos-view-page';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['pager'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['offset'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['header'] = FALSE;
/* Header: Global: View area */
$handler->display->display_options['header']['view']['id'] = 'view';
$handler->display->display_options['header']['view']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['header']['view']['field'] = 'view';
$handler->display->display_options['header']['view']['label'] = 'Featured gallery';
$handler->display->display_options['header']['view']['view_to_insert'] = 'image_galleries:block';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['footer'] = FALSE;
/* Footer: Global: View area */
$handler->display->display_options['footer']['view']['id'] = 'view';
$handler->display->display_options['footer']['view']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['footer']['view']['field'] = 'view';
$handler->display->display_options['footer']['view']['label'] = 'Gallery Thumbnails listing';
$handler->display->display_options['footer']['view']['view_to_insert'] = 'image_galleries:block_1';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['empty'] = FALSE;
/* No results behavior: Global: Text area */
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['id'] = 'area';
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['field'] = 'area';
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['empty'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['content'] = 'No Results for the year !1';
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['format'] = 'full_html';
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['tokenize'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['fields'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Nid */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['id'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['field'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Gallery Images */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_images']['id'] = 'field_gallery_images';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_images']['table'] = 'field_data_field_gallery_images';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_images']['field'] = 'field_gallery_images';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_images']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_images']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_images']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_images']['type'] = 'entityreference_entity_view';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_images']['settings'] = array(
  'view_mode' => 'full',
  'links' => 0,
);
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_images']['delta_offset'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_images']['separator'] = ' ';
/* Field: Content: Gallery Thumbnail */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_thumbnail']['id'] = 'field_gallery_thumbnail';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_thumbnail']['table'] = 'field_data_field_gallery_thumbnail';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_thumbnail']['field'] = 'field_gallery_thumbnail';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_thumbnail']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_thumbnail']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_thumbnail']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_thumbnail']['click_sort_column'] = 'fid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_thumbnail']['settings'] = array(
  'image_style' => '',
  'image_link' => '',
);
/* Field: Content: Image Gallery Subtitle */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image_gallery_subtitle']['id'] = 'field_image_gallery_subtitle';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image_gallery_subtitle']['table'] = 'field_data_field_image_gallery_subtitle';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image_gallery_subtitle']['field'] = 'field_image_gallery_subtitle';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image_gallery_subtitle']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image_gallery_subtitle']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image_gallery_subtitle']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Image Gallery Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image_gallery_title']['id'] = 'field_image_gallery_title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image_gallery_title']['table'] = 'field_data_field_image_gallery_title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image_gallery_title']['field'] = 'field_image_gallery_title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image_gallery_title']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image_gallery_title']['alter']['alter_text'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image_gallery_title']['alter']['text'] = '<div id="album-[nid]" class="album">
    <div class="slide-header slide-title">
        <h1>[field_image_gallery_title]</h1>
        <h2>[field_image_gallery_subtitle]</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-slider multimedia-slider">
        [field_gallery_images]
    </div>
</div>';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image_gallery_title']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image_gallery_title']['element_wrapper_type'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image_gallery_title']['element_default_classes'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['arguments'] = FALSE;
/* Contextual filter: Date: Date (node) */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['id'] = 'date_argument';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['field'] = 'date_argument';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['default_argument_type'] = 'date';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['granularity'] = 'year';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['use_fromto'] = 'no';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['date_fields'] = array(
  'node.created' => 'node.created',
);
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['filter_groups'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['filters'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = array(
  'image_gallery' => 'image_gallery',
);
/* Filter criterion: Date: Date (node) */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['id'] = 'date_filter';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['field'] = 'date_filter';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['exposed'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['expose']['operator_id'] = 'date_filter_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['expose']['label'] = 'Select Year';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['expose']['operator'] = 'date_filter_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['expose']['identifier'] = 'date_filter';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['expose']['remember_roles'] = array(
  2 => '2',
  1 => 0,
  11 => 0,
);
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['granularity'] = 'year';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['date_fields'] = array(
  'node.created' => 'node.created',
);
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'gallery/photos';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['type'] = 'normal';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['title'] = 'Photos';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['weight'] = '5';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['name'] = 'main-menu';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['context'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['context_only_inline'] = 0;

/* Display: Image Gallery Thumbnails */
$handler = $view->new_display('block', 'Image Gallery Thumbnails', 'block_1');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['css_class'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['pager'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'some';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['offset'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['default_row_class'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['row_class_special'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
$handler->display->display_options['row_options']['default_field_elements'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['fields'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Nid */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['id'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['field'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Gallery Images */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_images']['id'] = 'field_gallery_images';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_images']['table'] = 'field_data_field_gallery_images';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_images']['field'] = 'field_gallery_images';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_images']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_images']['exclude'] = TRUE;
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! So, what is the question?

Comment: Nothing is displayed when I select the year that has result.

Comment: Also on the autopreview the result is displayed, but not on the original page.

Comment: So far you stated facts, but you didn't ask any explicit question. What do you want to know? Put it in the form of a question, such as _What time is it?_

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have edited the post to highlight the question.

Comment: Hello Sir, any suggestions I need to go through?